# Kubectl patch gives: Error from server: cannot restore slice from map

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have this ingress object where I am trying to patch the `secretName`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world
...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.host
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.host
    secretName: my-secret
```

I would like to update the secret name using `kubectl patch` I have tried:

```
$ kubectl patch ing hello-world -p '{"spec":{"tls":{"secretName":"updated"}}}'
Error from server: cannot restore slice from map
```

and:

```
$ kubectl patch ing hello-world -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/tls/secretName", "value" : "updated"}]'
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tls` is an array/slice so you have to refer to it like that and include it in the original patch.

```
$ kubectl patch ing hello-world -p '{"spec":{"tls":[{"hosts":["my.host"], "secretName": "updated"}]}}'
```

A good way to get the `-p`s right (that works for me) is to convert them from YAML to JSON. You can try an online tool like [this](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json).

Comment: Using that approach I need to be careful to provide the existing "key" "my.host" else that will also get a new value. I would assume it would fail/skip if it did not find a matching  key. I only want to patch the secret name without having to worry about accidentally updating the hosts name as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's how the JSON is structured for the k8s object really; using an array (`tls` key). If you don't specify the part of the array element (the hash for `hosts`) then you will get an array with a single key/value element `secretname`

Comment: Using this approach `kubectl patch svc my-prometheus-grafana -n monitoring  -p '{"spec": {"ports": [{"name": "service", "port": 3000 }]}}'` giving this duplication error 
`The Service "my-prometheus-grafana" is invalid: spec.ports[1].name: Duplicate value: "service"` .. don't know why ?!

Answer (score 3):

You can update above json array field with following

```
kubectl patch ing hello-world --type json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/tls/0/secretName", "value" : "updated"}]'
```

Here, you have to specify the index, in your case it is 0